# Not able to insert unicode characters correctly to oracle db?

Tags: database, oracle, sql-insert

My Oracle charset is: AL32UTF8, here is a query that verifies this:

> SELECT value FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS   where parameter =
>   'NLS_CHARACTERSET';

I am doing the following insert query:

> insert into info (productid, productname) values (1,
>   SUBSTR('Blackberry®',1,20));

Here is how the data gets into the database:
productID: 1, productName: Blackberry�

I need to find a way to allow the ® character to appear correctly in the db.

Comment: What is your *client* character set, e.g. your NLS_LANG setting? It looks like a display issue when the value is retrieved by the client, rather than when it was inserted.

Comment: NLS_LANGUAGE: AMERICAN

Comment: NLS_LANGUAGE is (by default) derived from NLS_LANG, which [gives the locale](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch3globenv.htm#NLSPG189) including the character set. But to check another way, query NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS instead. If that shows the session/client NLS_CHARACTERSET is, say, US7ASCII then it won't handle the display of multibyte characters properly. Also, which client are you using?

Comment: Sorry I am using pl/sql developed client

Comment: I'd forgotten this isn't shown in NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS. You can see your NLS_LANG in the registry then, under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient...`, which points to your client ORACLE_HOME and related settings. You can modify it there if you're comfortable with the registry. Not sure if setting an NLS_LANG environment variable (through control panels) will override the registry setting. If you're using instant client then yo have to set the environment variable, I think.